# Knex : Altering Primary Key Id column Error

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

The database is built on Knex / PostgreSQL.
I would like to alter a table to add 'unique()' type to primary key Id column.
But Migration failed with an error message below.

> alter table "users" alter column "id" drop not null - column "id" is
>   in a primary key

```
exports.up = knex =>
  knex.schema
    .raw('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"')
    .createTable('users', table => {
      table
        .uuid('id')
        .primary()
        .notNullable()
        .defaultTo(knex.raw('uuid_generate_v4()'));
      table
        .string('companyName')
        .unique()
        .notNullable();
      table
        .string('username')
        .unique()
        .notNullable();
      table.string('password').notNullable();
      table.string('contactNo').notNullable();
      table.string('email').unique();
      table.string('address');
      table
        .boolean('isAdmin')
        .notNullable()
        .defaultTo(false);
      table
        .enum('businessType', ['catering', 'restaurant'])
        .defaultTo('catering');
      table.integer('lunchQty').defaultTo(null);
      table.integer('dinnerQty').defaultTo(null);
      table
        .uuid('bankAccountId')
        .references('id')
        .inTable('bank_account')
        .onDelete('SET NULL')
        .onUpdate('RESTRICT')
        .index();
      table.string('resetPasswordToken');
      table.timestamps(true, true);
    });

exports.down = knex => knex.schema.dropTable('users');
```

```
exports.up = knex =>
  knex.schema.alterTable('users', table => {
    table
      .uuid('id')
      .unique()
      .primary()
      .notNullable()
      .defaultTo(knex.raw('uuid_generate_v4()'))
      .alter();
  });

exports.down = knex =>
  knex.schema.table('users', table => {
    table.dropColumn('id').alter();
  });
```

> PostgreSQL version : 11.1
>
> Knex version : 0.19.2

I have searched here and there but couldn't find an answer for this issue.
Thanks for taking your time to help me out !

------------------------------ EDITION -----------------------------------
Qustion ) when I created delivery table like below. The error below accurred. I thought this was caused because I didn't set primary key unique.

> migration failed with error: alter table "delivery" add constraint
>   "delivery_userid_foreign" foreign key ("userId") references "users"
>   ("id") on update RESTRICT on delete CASCADE - there is no unique
>   constraint matching given keys for referenced table "users"

````
exports.up = knex =>
  knex.schema
    .raw('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"')
    .createTable('delivery', table => {
      table
        .uuid('id')
        .primary()
        .notNullable()
        .defaultTo(knex.raw('uuid_generate_v4()'));
      table
        .uuid('routeId')
        .references('id')
        .inTable('routes')
        .onDelete('CASCADE')
        .onUpdate('RESTRICT')
        .index();
      table
        .uuid('userId')
        .references('id')
        .inTable('users')
        .onDelete('CASCADE')
        .onUpdate('RESTRICT')
        .index();
      table.timestamps(true, true);
    });

exports.down = knex => knex.schema.dropTable('delivery');

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved the issue by removing alter users file !!
the 'unique key()' was the one that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Primary keys are already unique and not null: there is no need for your alteration. See [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS). Knex is trying to do what you ask, but in order to alter the table it would have to drop `id` which is in a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint.

Comment: Thanks @RichChurcher . I actually wanted alter primary key to resolve another issue. If Primary key itself is already unique, I don't know what causes the issue I have. Please check updated question !!

Comment: Does your `users` table really consist of just a single `id`? Can you show the current schema or full migration for `users`? Sometimes this sort of thing happens when there's a composite key.

Comment: Sorry, I've been unable to replicate your problem with the migrations you've provided (apart from removing the foreign key to bank account, as I don't have that table). I assume that something specific to your codebase elsewhere is interfering... sometimes this error occurs when a composite key is in play (because even if the `id` is unique, the combination of `id` and another column might not be). Good luck in your search!

Comment: Thanks for the advice ! @Rich Churcher